# Should soundscape ecology be a component of STEM education?

Tags: ecology, biophysics, learning, communication, bioacoustics

I'd like to see soundscape ecology be included in STEM education. I realize there is so much to teach and so little time, but think that primary and secondary students would be highly motivated and interested to learn about this topic and its importance to us all. A basic lesson including definition and examples of soundscapes from different realms (aerial, terrestrial, freshwater, marine, subterranean, etc.). Especially classes like biology that include "lab" components, it does not cost much to get a simple hydrophone and microphone and dat recorder and bring kids out to the field to listen and then show them how to look at acoustic data. It might be an exceptional way to integrate physics, biology, geography, and societal concepts into one lesson plan. Does anyone know of schools incorporating this? Example of some basic info (a bit too specialized): https://youtu.be/NplXdD616WM,  https://fieldnotes.nationalgeographic.org/expedition/listeningtofish, [http://www.fishecology.org/soniferous/Listening%20to%20fish%20children's%20book%20final%20wlinks.pdf](http://www.fishecology.org/soniferous/Listening%20to%20fish%20children%27s%20book%20final%20wlinks.pdf)

Comment: What's the question - should it, or is it?

Comment: The FishSounds project (https://fishsounds.net) just got a grant to produce classroom and lab materials for marine acoustic and soundscape education. Material should become available within the next year. We hadn't considered tracking which organizations or schools are using the material, but likely could (and I can see the benefit of the resulting dataset)

Comment: These sorts of opinion questions are frowned upon across the SE network; I know a bunch of you are interested in starting a new SE site, but I highly recommend immersing yourselves in what rules the site has found to work well for curated Q&A here and not bypassing them by upvoting every post by a fellow Area51 contributor - you're doing your colleagues a disservice.

Comment: God help education from hobby horse jockeys!